# Forming a giant array of multiple 64 x 64 matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am working video shot boundary detection using matlab. Here is my code snippet

```
clc;
clear all;

[file path] = uigetfile('*.avi','Pick a Video');% this line opens a pop up window so that you can choose your video for further processing     
video = VideoReader([path file]);% the video chosen through UI get stored in video object
numOfFrames = video.NumberOfFrames;% this will be a number (total number of frames in your chosen video)
%allFrames = read(video);% catching all the frames from the video in object allFrames
for i=1:1:numOfFrames
    try
        lFrame = read(video, i);%frames(:, :, :, i);
    catch
        break;
    end
    lRFrame = lFrame(:,:,1);
    lGFrame = lFrame(:,:,2);
    lBFrame = lFrame(:,:,3);
    lGray = 0.299*lRFrame + 0.587*lGFrame + 0.114*lBFrame;
    grayImage = imresize(lGray, [256 256]);

    % step 2 of the algorithm begins from here %
    meanFilterFunction = @(theBlockStructure) mean2(theBlockStructure.data(:)) * ones(1,1, class(theBlockStructure.data));

    blockSize = [4 4];
    blockyImage4 = blockproc(single(grayImage), blockSize, meanFilterFunction);
end
```

I am getting  a 64 x 64 image in `blockyImage4` but since it is in a loop , the value flushes itself in very next iteration every time.

I want an array of images which can store (possibly all) images(matrices). and i should have access to them all. if all the images could not be stored in an array then how to store only two images of consecutive iterations since i need 'i' and "i+1" th image to find out the diffrence between them. Please help

Comment: I don't sure that understood the question appropriately, but maybe `blockyImage4(:,:,i)=...` will help?

Comment: Do you need all images in RGB? Maybe you could convert frames to gray-scale (it would be easier to keep it in array). Basically you could keep it as an array of cells for example, where each and every cell keeps informations about every frame (cells may be very complex in Matlab)

Comment: @hesar There is already a conversion to gray scale present.

Comment: @Trilarion I noticed this to late :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to store 3D (x,y,time) data in Matlab? Do it either in a cell array or a 3D array. For the array don't forget to preallocate the needed size to avoid performance drops.

So either:

```
blockyimages = cell(numOfFrames, 1);
for i=1:1:numOfFrames
  ...
  blockyimages{i} = blockproc(single(grayImage), blockSize, meanFilterFunction);
end
% access the blocky image of the ith frame with blockyimages{i}
% you could even do blockyimages = cat(3, blockyimages{:}) to convert to a 3d matrix
```

or

```
blockyimages = zeros(64, 64, numOfFrames); % better frame sizes / block sizes
for i=1:1:numOfFrames
  ...
  blockyimages(:, :, i) = blockproc(single(grayImage), blockSize, meanFilterFunction);
end
% access the blocky image of the ith frame with blockyimages(:, :, i)
```

So, if you chose the second option and later want to do something with the blockyimages again, just make a second pass through the loop. For example if you want to compute the differences of consecutive blockyimages.

```
diffblockyimages = zeros(64, 64, numOfFrames - 1);
for i = 1 : numOfFrames - 1
  framei = blockyimages(:, :, i);
  frameiplusone = blockyimages(:, :, i+1);
  diffblockyimages(:, :, i) = frameiplusone - framei;
end
```

Although the same could have been achieved in the special case of the difference also as

```
diffblockyimages = diff(blockyimages, 1, 3);
```

Comment: blockyimages{i+1} is not working....how to access the next frame when we are in a loop

Comment: @user3184410 I never wrote blockyimages{i+1}?? in a loop one accesses frames by indices..

Comment: then how to access next (i+1)th image in a loop..plz help i am a new bee to matlab

Comment: @user3184410 not while processing the loop a first time because you cannot look into the future, but when you make the loop a second time (until the pre last frame only) you can do this, I will add an example to the solution

Comment: thanks @Trilarion...I really appreciate your kindness

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment is blocked I present possible  solution:
tested and works fine for me

```
    file_path = uigetfile('*.avi','Pick a Video');% this line opens a pop up window so that you can choose your video for further processing     
video = VideoReader(file_path);% the video chosen through UI get stored in video object
numOfFrames = video.NumberOfFrames;% this will be a number (total number of frames in your chosen video)
%allFrames = read(video);% catching all the frames from the video in object allFrames

all_frames = cell(1,numOfFrames);
for i=1:numOfFrames %default step is always 1
    try
        lFrame = read(video, i);%frames(:, :, :, i);
    catch
        break;
    end
    lGray = rgb2gray(lFrame);
    grayImage = imresize(lGray, [256 256]);
all_frames{1,i} = grayImage;

end
```

now you have all frames in all_frames array
access is easy:

```
img1 = all_frames{1,1}; imshow(img1);
img2 = all_frames{1,2}; imshow(img2);
```

Comment: @hesarThanks for the reply but your code does not address two things 1. conversion of every image into 64 x 64 blocks by dividing 256x256 into blocks of 4x4 and taking the mean. also what i want to do is to take the diffrence between two consecutive frames only (i and i+1) so will it be possible to store 1st and 2nd image into an array take their mean and empty the array. then store 3rd and 4th image take their mean and empty the array again

Comment: @user3184410 you can do this definitely the same way, you can put everything as cell or use more dimensions of cell array to store more information. For example all_frames = cell(3,numOfFrames) where you have 3 rows keeping respectively: cell of divided blocks, mean of blocks, difference value. All values can be calculated inside for loop and saved into cell array. Remember to skip first iteration of loop cause you can't calculate difference. img1 and img2 can be temporary values to not keep them in memory. This one is just example of use cell array to store results